# Query a table by using foreign key navigation properties in LINQ with C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following **LINQ to SQL EF** classes:

[image: LINQtoSQL EF class diagram]

with the foreign key relationship on **SessionId** (primary table **WebinarSession**).

I would like, **by using lambdas** to select all the **WebinarSession** rows that concern a specific product line.

I put as example this code that of course **DOES NOT WORK**(it would owrk with **Single** inseatd of **Where** but it is not applicable because I have mulitple instances matching the condition):

```
SessionId = _webinarRecordingsDB.WebinarSessions.Where(m => m.SessionId == m.SessionSubjects.Where(n => n.ProductLineName == productLine).SessionId);
```

Where **_webinarRecordingsDB** is the EF object mapping the **SQL Database**.

Does anybody know how to fulfill this task? Thanks

Comment: FYI - those aren't **LINQ to SQL EF classes** they are EF model classes :)

Comment: @James: I specified LINQ to SQL because you can create EF classes also by using ADO.NET

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var sessions = _webinarRecordingsDB.WebinarSessions.Where(w => w.SessionSubjects.Any(s => s.ProductLine == productLine));
```

When you define a foreign key in EF (or Linq to SQL classes) the designer should automatically create a property which would allow you direct access to the table from your entity (in your case your WebinarSession object should have a property called SessionSubjects).

Comment: thanks for your answer. So there is no need to make the comparison WebinarSession.SessionId == SessionSubject.SessionId?

Comment: @Francesco - If you access the **WebinarSession.SessionSubject** property then no as the records will already be filtered based on the SessionId (as defined by your Foreign key contraint).

Comment: It also works with: **_webinarRecordingsDB.SessionSubjects.Where(m => m.ProductLineName == productLine).Select(m => m.WebinarSession)**

Comment: @Francesco - Pretty much the same thing as your foreign key object will have a reference to the the primary. Which one you want to use is up to you, it all comes down to readability I suppose.