# LINQ to table by foreign key in another table

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

i have three tables as follow

1. course(id, name, desc)
2. students(id, name, courceId)
3. users(id, name, courseId)

[see img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl4i2.jpg)

I need to get students of course which current user assigned to.

my issue is how to get table records which has foreign key for a table
I did the following, however the code sample visits the DB twice.Is there any way to make it one visit.

```
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var courseId = _context.Users
            .Where(u => u.Id == userId)
            .Select(u => u.CourseId)
            .Single();

        var students = _context.Students
            .Where(s => s.CourseId == courseId)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: so, code first, model first, or database first? if you properly set `User` and `Students` you could call `_context.Users.Include("Student")` for lazily loads Student relation (be it two or three, or just one query, is up to **entity framework**, nothing much we can do.. but it tend to be efficient anyway)

Comment: Please do at least some **minimal** research before you post a question. Enter your title [in google](https://www.google.com/#q=LINQ+to+table+by+foreign+key+in+another+table) and check the first result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query a table by using foreign key navigation properties in LINQ with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764013/query-a-table-by-using-foreign-key-navigation-properties-in-linq-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Its code first. these are arbitrary tables so bare with me illustrate my point.

Comment: students are not related to users with anything. only relation is by course Id on both tables students and users.

Comment: Can you please add the POCO classes of student and Courses in the question

Comment: ty eldho ^^. it worked according to zaitsman answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like in T-SQL, you need a join:

```
     var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

var students = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId)
.Join(_context.Students, u => u.CourseId, s => s.CourseId, (u,s) => s)
.ToList();
```